# What is COMMENT in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have seen a code snippet like this`person_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mass casualty patient ID', what is the usage of this COMMENT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Comment" is a popular term of art in software development.  I won't reiterate the meaning as I'm sure you know it, but MySQL allows you to add comments to a column as part of the DDL: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

> A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 255 characters long. The comment is displayed by the SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW FULL COLUMNS statements.